# How to set focus to a bound ListboxItem by pressing its child element?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, listboxitem

I am developping a small WPF application which consist mostly in displaying `ObservableCollection<>` in others `ObservableCollection<>`, and so on.

Here is a code example of what my application looks like:

```xml
<Listbox Name="MainList" ItemsSource={Binding}>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>      

                <Textblock Text={Binding MainName} />
                <Button>Add item</Button>
                <Button>Delete item</Button>

                <Listbox Name="ChildList" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ChildItem}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Textblock Text={Binding ChildName} />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </Listbox>

            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</Listbox>
```

And visually it pretty much looks like this:

[image: Application example]

**EDIT:**

I will re-explain what I am trying to do.

- Whenever I click `Button A` or `Button B` I want to Select the `MainList` `ListBoxItem` in which they are contained (i.e: `A Item`)
- And in a second time whenever I click `Button B`:

  - I want to be sure that a `ListBoxItem` is selected in `ChildList`(Second Listbox in the picture)
  - And if so, I want to delete it in code-behind.

But my main problem is since everything is generated by my bindings I cannot get, so far, an element from my `ChildList` because `ChildList` is duplicated in any of my `MainList` `ListBoxItem`.

Comment: Do you have to use `DataTemplate` ? `A item` or `B item` could be `UserControl`. This way, it should be a lot more easier.

Comment: when `Button` is clicked do you want to select `MainItem` `ListBoxItem` container, give it focus or both?

Comment: @NicolasVoron Well so far my whole code uses DataTemplates to bind my different ObservableCollection<T>. So I would really like to stick with that.

Comment: @dkozl When any of the two Buttons are clicked, I want to select the MainItem ListBoxItem in which they are contained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well the problem is that you want first click on a button of unselected item to select the `MainItem`, and on next click, when `MainItem` is already selected, preform click action. Try this when button is clicked:

```
private ListBoxItem FindItemContainer(DependencyObject obj)
{
   while (obj != null && !(obj is ListBoxItem))
   {
       obj = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(obj);
   }

   if (obj != null)
       return obj as ListBoxItem;
   else
       return null;
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var lbi = FindItemContainer(sender as DependencyObject);
   if (lbi != null)
   {
       if (lbi.IsSelected)
       {
           //do click event
       }
       else
           lbi.IsSelected = true;
   }
}
```

Of course you can also do it more MVVM way by binding `ListBoxItem.IsSelected` to lets say `bool MainItem.MyItemIsSelected`

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=MyItemIsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

and `Button.Command` to your `ICommand MainItem.DeleteCommand` and then when command is executed do something like that:

```
if (MyItemIsSelected)
{
    //do command body
}
else
    MyItemIsSelected = true;
```

which will be better long term because you could replicate `SelectedItem` behaviour in `ChildList` object (add `MyItemIsSelected` and bind it to inner `'ListBoxItem.IsSelected`, like discribed above) and add `MySelectedItem` property to `ChildList`:

```
ChildItem MySelectedItem
{
   get
   {
      return Items.FirstOrDefault(n=>n.MyItemIsSelected);
   }
}
```

and your delete command would look like this:

```
if (MyItemIsSelected)
{
    ChildItem selItem = ChildItems.MySelectedItem;
    if (selItem != null) ChildItems.Items.Remove(selItem);
}
else
    MyItemIsSelected = true;
```

if everything is data bound and lists are `ObservableCollections` then you can do all that in object and UI will follow. Actually you can do only this child selection binding bit and still use first solution and in `Button_Click` look like this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var lbi = FindItemContainer(sender as DependencyObject);
   if (lbi != null)
   {
       if (lbi.IsSelected)
       {
           MainItem mainItem = lbi.Content as MainItem;
           ChildItem selChild = mainItem.ChildItems.MySelectedItem;
           if (selChild != null) mainItem.ChildItems.Items.Remove(selChild);
       }
       else
           lbi.IsSelected = true;
   }
}
```

Here is simple, working example on [Dropbox](http://db.tt/fd2Jed2N)

Comment: Thank you very much for the effort you have put in this answer. You explanation helped me to solve my problem in other ways. I have changed 50% of my Classes in the ObservableCollections<>. Thanks to you code refactoring was way easier than I had expected !

Answer (score 0):

You can do everything you want to do in code behind:

- Find the item on which the Button is pressed: in the click-event, cast the sender parameter to type Button. Its DataContext property will contain the item you want to select.
- Select the item: set MainList.SelectedItem to the item.
- Focus will be on the Button, but that should be ok, since it is inside the item.
- Find the selected item in second listbox: locating the ListBox in the DataTemplate is tricky, but you could set its IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem property to True, and then use the underlying child collection's default CollectionView. You'd find the current item of MainList like above. Then you'd use:

  `itemToDelete = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(item.ChildItems).CurrentItem;
  item.ChildItems.Remove(itemToDelete);`